# Need to convert human voice into musical notes

Tags: performance

A human sings a musical tone and wants to convert into a musical instrument playing the same. On processing the .wav file of the recorded human voice using [aubio.org](http://aubio.org), I am able to get the pitch/frequency at different time intervals. But how to get the notes of musical instruments to be played from this data or Is there some tuner that can help me do this ?

Comment: I have the same requirement can you help me with the solution you have found.

Answer (score 2):

For pitch, use the formula that MIDI 69 = 440hz, so (python/pseudo code)

```
midiNote = round(12 * (log(freq/440.0), 2))) + 69
```

But you'll find that things can actually be more complex than this for rhythm because.  I'd use an already made rhythmic "quantization" package (that's the Google search term you'll want) because determining both the tempo and whether something that is 1.125 beats long should be transcribed as a quarter note or a quarter note tied to a 32nd note will depend a lot on context and it's a big programming job.  There are several preexisting toolkits that will do it for you.  My own python framework music21 has an audioSearch module that should do the trick for simple pieces -- at least you could take the code there and put it into your own package, since it's pretty standard FFT sample conversion techniques.

Comment: Thanks Michael. You are correct about the need of rhythmic quantization, because just playing the midiNote calculated from the formula at the specific time intervals plays some bizarre tune. Actually I had to shift from Python to Android (Java, c or c++). I have the recorder and note generation ready, but I am not getting a way to add rhythmic quantization to it. Would really appreciate any further suggestions for it.